# Getalldocumentsbykey function get empty string means?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

```
Set timeVc=timeVw.Allentries
    Set tobeDeleted=timeVw.Getalldocumentsbykey("", true)
    Call tobeDeleted.removeall(True)
```

Just now want to confirm what is the meaning of getalldocumentbykey with empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetAllDocumentsByKey with an empty string as first parameter returns an **empty collection**.

If you want to get all documents with an empty value in view's first sorted column then change the formula of your first sorted column to

```
@If(YourFieldName = ""; " "; YourFieldName)
```

It has a space instead of an empty string now.

```
Set tobeDeleted=timeVw.Getalldocumentsbykey(" ", true)
```

returns all those documents then.

Comment: ok get it. i check previous ppl coding, put a space " ", thought what happend. normally i will put a Keystring to search for an item.  Thanks ~